# Read file from s3a along with AWS Athena SDK (1.11+)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am writing a spark/scala program which submits a query on athena (using `aws-java-sdk-athena:1.11.420`) and waits for the query to complete. Once the query is complete, my spark program directly reads from the S3 bucket using `s3a` protocol (the output location of the query) using spark's `sparkSession.read.csv()` function.

In order to read the CSV file, I need to use `org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-aws:1.8+` and `org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-client:1.8+`. Both of these libraries are build using AWS SDK version `1.10.6`. However, AWS athena does not have any SDK with that version. The oldest version they have is `1.11+`.

How can I resolve the conflict? I need to use the latest version of AWS SDK to get access to athena, but `hadoop-aws` pushed me back to an older version?

Are there other dependency version of `hadoop-aws` that uses `1.11+` AWS SDKs? If so, what are the versions that will work for me? If not, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can use `hadoop-aws:3.1+` which comes with `aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.11+`. This AWS SDK Bundle comes with Athena packaged.

I although still need to run spark with `hadoop-commons:3.1+` libraries. The spark cluster I have runs 2.8 version libraries.

Due to my spark cluster running 2.8, spark-submit jobs were failing, while normal execution of the jar (`java -jar myjar.jar`) was working fine. This is because Spark was replacing the hadoop libraries I provided with the version it was bundled with.

Comment: Hadoop 2.9 has "HADOOP-14040. Use shaded aws-sdk uber-JAR 1.11.86."; this is the first of the 2.x line with that 1.11 SDK. AWS SDKs are very fussy and you can't safely drop in old versions; if you can go up to 2.9.x for all the spark hadoop dependencies things should work